# Как доработать регулярное выражение, что бы имя функции попадало в отдельную группу?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vb.net

Имеется такая функция, которая парсит строку вида `SUM(H)`.

Данная функция находит по регулярному выражению имя функции с аргументами, далее находятся только аргументы и в упрощенном варианте берется только один аргумент.

Как доработать регулярное выражение, что бы имя функции попадало в отдельную группу?

```vb
Protected Function parse_formula(formula As String) As String

    Dim pattern As String = "\b[^()]+\((.*)\)$"
    Dim regex As New Regex(pattern)

    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(formula)
    Dim arguments = match.Groups(1).Value

    Dim argument = Regex.Match(arguments, "([^,]+\(.+?\))|([^,]+)")

    Return argument.Value

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```vb
> Dim pattern As String = "\b[^()]+\((.*)\)$"
> ```

```vb
Dim pattern As String = "(\w+)\((.*)\)$"
```

Comment: А чем отличается то, оно и так и так выдает имя функции вместе со скобками и аргументами. А надо чистое имя функции и имя функции с аргументами.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Не в той группе смотрел.